# Lambda Function Does not Add Rule to Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this python 3.7 code that runs as well from my local computer.  This is the code for my lambda function. However, when I test it in AWS, it does not add the inbound rule to the security group.  I would like help in getting it to work.  Again, when I run it from my local computer, it works.

```
    import boto3
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    
    def modify_sg_add_rules(event, context):
            response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
            GroupName='boto3-sg',
            IpPermissions=[
                { 
                    'FromPort': 1521,
                    'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                    'IpRanges': [
                        {
                            'CidrIp': '12.345.67.890/32',
                            'Description': 'My home IP',
                        },
                    ],
                    'ToPort': 1521,
                },
                ],
                DryRun=False
            ) #closes response
            return response

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    modify_sg_add_rules()
```

These are the permission in the policy that is attached to a role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, help me!
Thank you!
--Willie

Comment: Permissions are correct. Can you show the actual lambda code, not your script on local workstation? Also, did you check CloudWatch Logs for any errors?

Comment: The above is the actual lambda code.  Thanks!

Comment: I see, the handler is `modify_sg_add_rules`. Code and permissions are correct. The cider `'12.345.67.890/32'` is wrong, but I guess it is only for SO. Have you checked CW Logs?

Comment: The cider is just that I did not want to place the actual home IP there.  That cider is fake.  CloudWatch does not show any errors.  This is what is in CloudWatch:  START RequestId: ff3f0f2f-9c9a-4d07-9f54-50527a88a55f Version: $LATEST

2020-12-21T01:20:43.057-05:00 Loading function
2020-12-21T01:20:43.060-05:00 value1 = value1
2020-12-21T01:20:43.060-05:00 value2 = value2

2020-12-21T01:20:43.060-05:00 value3 = value3
2020-12-21T01:20:43.061-05:00 END RequestId: ff3f0f2f



Copy
REPORT RequestId: ff3f0f2f  Duration: 1.56 ms Billed Duration: 2 ms

Comment: This is the name of the handler in the runtime settings:  lambda_function.lambda_handler

Comment: There is no `lambda_handler` function in your code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I was just referring to the name in the **Runtime settings**, and not in the function code itself.  I was just wondering if that has anything to do with the code not doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: AWS will try to invoke `lambda_handler` method. You don't have such method, so it can't work.

Comment: I think that is the part that I do not know how to do: adding a lambda_handler method.

Comment: Just rename `modify_sg_add_rules` into `lambda_handler`.

Comment: Yes! That did it!  Also, I would like to note that after renaming the function from modify_sg_add_rules to lamdba_function, I also had to click on **Deploy**.  Even after changing the name of the function to lambda_function, it did not work until I clicked on **Deploy**.  Thanks a bunch, Marcin. It works!

Comment: No, I do not mind. Please go ahead and provide the answer for future reference. If there is anything I should do such as to make sure you get credit for helping me figure this out, please let me know.  I am not sure how that works here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. You could accept it, which is done by clicking on a "tick" button under upvote/donwvote buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **wrong name** for [lambda function handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html). Instead of `modify_sg_add_rules` it should be `lambda_handler` which is default name for the handler.

Thus, the solution was to **rename** `modify_sg_add_rules` into `lambda_handler`. The alternative is to change the default handler's name into `modify_sg_add_rules`.